# Backup Data Rollback failure Issue in magento 1.9.3.4

Tags: database, magento-1

I have deleted all the database from `/var/backups` folder. but I  have  a copy of those database in my local hard drive so I copy database and paste in `/var/backups`
Now Database is showing in admin but when i try to rollback it shows loading but nothing happens.

[image]

It also showing wrong date of database and when i add more database in `var/backups` folder
it shows error
[image]

Comment: It may help if you go to the var/report folder and check for the error log to get some hint.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have access to your hosting service? Usually, Magento tools (backup, import, export) never works.

I suggest you to use phpMyAdmin from your hosting to import the database. You just go to your database, click **Import** and select your .sql file. Or, if you have SSH access, you can also do it using this command:

```
mysql -u [username] -p [database_name] < [dumpfilename.sql]
```